# unable to create new pages in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, publishing-page

I have created new Page using  by clicking New button in SharePoint online Pages Library.

It creates a page with random name, with blank screen.

[image]

The random name for page is shown below

[image]

Is there any setting I need to make.

till yesterday at around 3.30 pm when i created a page using "Add a page" option and type in the name it creates the web page for sharepoint. but now if i went to create a page it just takes to to a different style with this "/SitePages/4c3c7j05.aspx?Mode=Edit" at the end of the url

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to change two settings:

Go to Admin center > SharePoint > settings.
url would like:

https://tenantname-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/TenantSettings.aspx

Here change the lists and libraries experience to Classic experience and save the changes. Check screenshot below:

[image]

Also at the list/library level, go to the settings page > advanced settings and change it Classic experience as below. Here default experience would be the one set at the tenant level. So you can set the value as default experience or classic experience:

[image]

Also if you want to ensure that there no more surprises, i would suggest turning off the first release feature using steps mentioned below:

- Go to the Office 365 admin center.
- Navigate to Settings > Organization profile.
- Next to Release preferences, click Edit.
- To disable first release, choose Standard release, then click Next,    and say Yes to the confirmation. Skip to the last step.

Comment: i dont really mind list and library looking modern. but when you create pages it comes with issues as mentioned above. can we disable the new look for page and site creation alone ?

Comment: No we can't do that site collection level unfortunately, but if you want to get it at pages/site pages level, you need to go to individual list settings and change the experience.

Comment: till yesterday at around 3.30 pm when i created a page using "Add a page" option and type in the name it creates the web page for sharepoint. but now if i went to create a page it just takes to to a different style with this "/SitePages/4c3c7j05.aspx?Mode=Edit" at the end of the url .

Comment: i did as advised but no luck

Comment: did you change the release preferences from first release to standard release ?

Comment: Looks like you need to raise a ticket with Microsoft.

Comment: yes i did that, i will open up a ticket, thanks for your help Gautham